# Dont receive message with confluent kafka simple producer/consumer examples?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

I run `kafka_2.11-0.10.1.1` with `confluent-kafka-0.9.2` (master branch) python bindings which uses `librdkafka-0.9.2`. My machine runs ubuntu-16.04 x86_64. I run `zookeeper-3.4.8-1` on port `2181`. I run confluent **producer** example like so:

```
$ cd confluent-kafka-python/examples
$ python producer.py localhost:9095 confluent-01
first message
2nd msg
```

and the **consumer**:

```
$ python consumer.py localhost:9095 confluentgroup confluent-01
```

Everything runs locally on my machine, which does not run any firewall.

**Remarks**:

- the topic is successfully created on Zookeeper
- the broker successfully receives the producer messages:
- the consumer sets following conf `{'bootstrap.servers': broker, 'group.id': group, 'session.timeout.ms': 6000, 'default.topic.config': {'auto.offset.reset': 'smallest'}, 'api.version.request': True }`
- in the beginning `producer/consumer` work fine for some time, until I get `Receive failed: Disconnected` on the producer side. Exerpt:

---

```
$ python producer.py  localhost:9095 confluent-02
asd
% Message delivered to confluent-02 [0]
1234123
890890
% Message delivered to confluent-02 [0]
%3|1485791262.420|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:obscura.ax.example.com:9095/3]: obscura.ax.example.com:9095/3: Receive failed: Disconnected
```

**Problem**: I don't get anything on the consumer side after a while

Questions:

1. What am i doing wrong?
2. **How can I verify the producer messages have been received on the broker side?**
   The producer messages are properly received on the broker side.
3. **How can I debug the consumer side?**
   I added `'debug': "cgrp, topic, fetch"` to consumer conf. Where can I read the logs?

Comment: Can you try and replace localhost with actual `ip` or `hostname` of the machine you are running this on?

Comment: @Gondola_Ride the broker successfully gets the msg from the producer (from log). My problem is the consumer does not do anything.

Comment: I am confused about the version you are using? What is the broker version and what is the client version? Clients cannot connect to older broker -- maybe that's the problem?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax librdkafka is backwards compatible with older brokers so it should be fine.

Comment: @m-ric What happens if you produce new messages while the consumer is running? If you get new messages that means the group has offsets committed so it wont start reading at the beginning of the partition (`auto.offset.reset=smallest`). If you dont get the new messages it means something else is wrong: connectivity or assignment. You can debug both with setting the `debug` config property to `broker,cgrp,topic`

Comment: @Edenhill if I start the consumer _before_ the producer, I get the message. I need to `ctrl+d` the producer to make it commit its messages. Newline is not enough. I dont understand the correlation b/w "the group has offsets committed" so "it wont start reading at the beginning"?

Comment: See these docs for an introduction how kafka consumers work, pay attention to committed offsets and auto.offset.reset: http://docs.confluent.io/3.1.2/clients/consumer.html

Comment: @Edenhill thanks. I added `'debug': 'cgrp, topic, fetch'` to the consumer conf. Where can I read the logs? Could not find it after a quick search in the librdkafka doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made things work eventually. Initially I ran the [confluent-kafka tutorial](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python), which:

- does not trap `ctrl+c` SIGINT signal,
- does not time out while in `poll()`

in the consumer code. Thus I had to `ctrl+z` then `kill %1` it on my linux machine. I believe this termination did not close the socket, which stayed open for some time (`TIME_WAIT`). Then when I restarted the consumer, it pulled garbage from the older socket and got stuck.

I added `try: [...] except KeyboardInterrupt: consumer.close()` to catch the `ctrl+c` and close the socket cleany. And no longer faced the issue.

I hope this will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions:

1) try to add the option --from-beginning to the consumer command

2) the default port for brokers is 9092 so check the right port to use

Hope this helps.

Comment: 1) examples/consumer.py already defines `'auto.offset.reset': 'smallest'`
2) the producer successfully sent message on localhost:9093

Comment: auto.oofset.reset is the policy that Kafka applies when no offsets have been committed. Your consumer is not consuming because it have already read all the messages so the option --from-beginning in the Kafka shell tells to the consumer to start to conusme from the begin. You can change the consumer group in order to read all messages.